# Segmentation fault when dereferencing vector of iterators

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'd like to use a vector of iterators to link to the contents of a vector< int>.
When I try to fill said vector of iterators via a single iterator "it" I get a segmentation fault when I try to dereference it.

```
vector <int> vec;
vector <int>::iterator it = vec.begin();
vector<vector <int>::iterator> vecIt(3);
vec.push_back(1);    
vec.push_back(2);
vec.push_back(3);
vecIt[0] = it;

cout << *vecIt[0] << endl; //this line causes seg. fault
```

However, if I do not use my "it" iterator, it works just fine:

```
vector <int> vec;
vector<vector <int>::iterator> vecIt(3);
vec.push_back(1);  
vec.push_back(2);
vec.push_back(3);
vecIt[0] = vec.begin();

cout << *vecIt[0] << endl;
```

Could someone explain this behavior to me? What causes the seg. fault when using an extra iterator?
Also, is there a better way of going through my vector< int> and saving iterators (or pointers, if that is more advisable) to the vector of iterators?

Comment: You are running afoul of the [Iterator validation rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

Comment: You invalidate the iterators when you `push_back`.

Comment: Thank you for the link @NathanOliver!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back

> If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

Thus, by taking the iterator (it's an empty vector, too) and then making the vector's size exceed its capacity by calling `push_back()`, you are invalidating that iterator. However, when you do `push_back()` and *then* take the iterator, no invalidation occurs as the vector's size does not exceed its capacity.

Comment: Thank you! I moved the line initializing "it" to after the push-backs and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 3):

When you push a new element via

```
vec.push_back(1);
```

The iterators get invalidated. See e.g. at [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/):

> If a reallocation happens, all iterators, pointers and references related to the container are invalidated.
>   Otherwise, only the end iterator is invalidated, and all iterators, pointers and references to elements are guaranteed to keep referring to the same elements they were referring to before the call.